# removing this black border for input in tailwindcss react

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i am having this weird black border for my input search when i use this example.

```
    <div class="shadow flex">
        <input class="w-full rounded p-2" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button class=" w-auto flex justify-end items-center text-blue p-2 hover:text-blue-light">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </button>
   </div>
```

not only that example above but i think with any tailwindcss example i tried that has border will auto show this weird black border

[image]

as you can see there is no black border on the search icon except for shadow
is there anyway to disable this in taiwindcss for react?

Comment: you should remove `shadow` class from div element.

Answer (score 0):

on the input tag add this on className

`<input classname="outline-none border-none" />`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the shadow class from the parent element element or maybe add padding to it to differentiate it from it child's element then add "border-none" to the input element

```
 <div class=" p-10 flex">
        <input class="w-full rounded p-2 border-none" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button class=" w-auto flex justify-end items-center text-blue p-2 hover:text-blue-light">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </button>
   </div>
```